# Pythonw, pyw, & arg, /B won't make python's http-server run in background

Tags: python-3.x, windows, background-process, httpserver

I've tried every method in the title to run it in the background but here are the issues i got trying to use them:

pythonw and pyw: server doesn't work, going to localhost:8000 error with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
& arg and START/B: doesn't start script in background and instead output server log

so now I'm short on ideas on how to run this script in the background.

Comment: Did you find the chance to try out my proposed solution? Did you find another one?

Answer (score 3):

Using `pythonw`, it should help to explicitly redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file – maybe this behavior is somehow related to the problem described [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue706263) (although this seems to be specific to Python 2.7). Not capturing the output by redirecting it to `os.devnull` seems to work as well.

The following script produces a minimum working server example with `pythonw` for me (using Python 3.7.9):

```
import http.server
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")

    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("localhost", 8000), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good solution for starting an http server in the background.

This solution is a bit of a hack, but it works quite well on my computer.

Use the `subprocess` module in a separate `.pyw` file to start the server script stored in a `.py` file.

**launch.pyw**

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
            ["python.exe", "http_server.py"], 
            creationflags=0x08000000,         # use this "non creation window" flag if 
                                              # working with pyinstaller
)
```

**http_server.py**

```py
import http.server

# your code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("localhost", 8000), 
            http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now, you should start your server with `launch.pyw` script.